# Matching impedance of the load after inverting

Tags: arduino, switches, inverter, impedance-matching

I have a very basic inverter circuit with a 2n3053. I basically need around 5V at the collector terminal when the base is at 0V. I am able to achieve this provided the load is not connected. When the load is connected at the collector, the 5V drops to around 0.6 V or so (depending on the pull up resistor). After going through the load's data sheet I realized that there is an input impedance of 1.5K ohm. I could reduce the pull up resistor value to 100 ohms, but don't want to do so because of the high current that will flow through it.

I don't know much about impedance matching but I think that's the way to sort this problem out. Could someone help me? Can I make an emitter follower to match the impedance?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhYmYo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Switch to PNP and use the load itself as the pull-down resistor?

Comment: Could it be that you need to get rid of the collector resistor, connect your load's CTRL input directly to the collector, and the 5V Reference to +5V?  What is your load, BTW?

Comment: I guess I could do that just remove the resistor altogether. My load is an [LED driver](http://www.luxdrive.com/content/3021-BuckPuck.pdf). I'll probably just remove the resistor altogther. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score -1):

I you need rail-to-rail output, you should use a class D output (replace R1 by a PNP - this may need adaptation when you attack the base to avoid excessive current - or better replace both bipolar by an NMOS and a PMOS).